# R dimnames of matrix, strange behaviour

Tags: r

Is this a bug in R or does it make sense?

```
## works
aa <- matrix(nrow=1,ncol=2)
dimnames(aa)[[2]] <- c("a","b")
dimnames(aa)[[1]] <- c("c")

## does not work
bb <- matrix(nrow=1,ncol=2)
dimnames(bb)[[1]] <- c("c")
Error in dimnames(bb)[[1]] <- c("c") : 'dimnames' must be a list
```

Thanks for explanations !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is expected behavior. When you assign to an index of an element of an object, R will create the element if it doesn't exist. In your example "dimnames" doesn't exist in `aa`, so R tries to create "dimnames" based on what you're assigning to it. Consider assigning elements named "a", "b", and "c" of a list:

```
> L <- list()
> L$a[[1]] <- 5
> L$b[[3]] <- "foo"
> L$c[[4]] <- c(1,2,3)
> class(L$a)
[1] "numeric"
> class(L$b)
[1] "character"
> class(L$c)
[1] "list"
```

Now the problem with saying `L$a[[1]] <- anything` is that `L$a` doesn't exist yet. What happens when an element doesn't exist is that R just creates the simplest type of element that would work. As you can see, `L$a[[1]] <- 5` would make sense if `L$a` is a numeric vector, so R makes it a numeric vector. `L$b[[3]] <- "foo"` doesn't make sense if `L$b` is a numeric vector, but it would make sense if `L$b` is a character vector, so that's what R creates. But `L$c[[4]] <- c(1,2,3)` can only happen if `L$c` is a list, so in that case you get a list.

In your case, it tries to create `dimnames` according to that rule; so it makes `dimnames(aa)` a list, but it only makes `dimnames(bb)` a character vector. But `dimnames` has an extra constraint that it has to be a list, so it objects and you get an error.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
dimnames(bb)[[1]] <- list("c")
```

This command will assign the name as a row name.

I suppose the error is due to the list of dimnames not being created. Otherwise if you access the second part of the list first (`[[2]]`), the list will be created. Therefore, you can also access `dimnames[[1]]` afterwards.

Comment: I'm actually surprised that works; `aa$b[[1]] <- list("c")` makes `aa$b` a list _containing_ a list, which isn't what you want with `dimnames`. Using the single brackets i.e. `dimnames(aa)[1] <- list("c")` also works and is more consistent with how R behaves elsewhere.

Comment: @crowding I agree, that it's more consistent to use single brackets. But actually, the results of `dimnames(aa)[1] <- list("c")`and `dimnames(aa)[[1]] <- list("c")` are identical.

Answer (score 0):

I would do what the error says:

```
dimnames(bb)[[1]] <- list("c")
> bb
  [,1] [,2]
c   NA   NA
```

What also works:

```
dimnames(bb)[[1]] <- "c"
```